# Two Date Picker fragments - how to edit date separately?

Tags: android, date, picker

I was following the date picker Android tutorial. Unfortunately, after doing it, I realized it applies only to one of my text fields and to be honest, I have no idea how to apply it to the other one, DateEdit2. That is, clicking on either DateEdit1 or DateEdit2 I edit DateEdit1. I understand this comes from the function of setting the date, but any attempt to change or pass the button as argument causes error, as these methods cannot be edited this way. Any ideas?

here is the code:

```
 public void showTruitonDatePickerDialog(View v) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }

    public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            // Do something with the date chosen by the user
            DateEdit1.setText(DateEdit1.getText() + " " + day + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year);
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance,
John

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have to Text Fields - DateEdit1 and DateEdit2. When I use either of them they change date on DateEdit1. How to make them work separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a global `public boolean isDateEdit1;` in activity.

In the `onClickListener` from `DateEdit1`, before calling `showTruitonDatePickerDialog(View v)`, set `isDateEdit1 = true;`.

In the `onClickListener` from `DateEdit2`, before calling `showTruitonDatePickerDialog(View v)`, set `isDateEdit1 = false;`.

Then, in the `onDateSet`:

```
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        if(getActivity.isDateEdit1){
          DateEdit1.setText(""+day + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year);
          return;
        }
        DateEdit2.setText("" + day + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year);
    }
```

Comment: Since not much more info is present, this is likely the simplest solution.  Though I'd have done it slightly different.

Comment: How would you reform it?

Answer (score 0):

I created another class that extends `DialogFragment` with another name and used a different function:

```
public void showTruitonDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}

public void datePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new SecondDatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker1");
}

public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
        DateEdit1.setText(DateEdit1.getText() + " " 
              + day + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year);
    }
}

public static class SecondDatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
        DateEdit2.setText(DateEdit2.getText() + " "
            + day + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year);
    }
}
```

It's not great, but it works for me.
So, on the first `onClickListener()`, call the `showTruitonDatePickerDialog()`, and then on the second `onClickListener()`, call the `datePickerDialog()`.